# How to get the following date '1333504225' in to '0000-00-00' with php?

Tags: php

For some reason this is how I get the date. I have tried using php to decode it but I get the wrong date.

```
$datetst ='1333504225';
$date = strtotime($datetst);
echo date("F j, Y", $date);
```

What I plan to do with this is calculate the difference in days from (today-the day the record was created). Which is why I need to have it in '0000-00-00'. I am no expert, but our engineer is of no help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to convert your unix timestamp again by `strtotime`

just use this

```
$datetst =1333504225;
echo date("F j, Y", $datetst);
```

and to get difference in days use below code

```
$datetst = 1333504225;
echo "Date : ".date("F j, Y", $datetst);
$diff = time() - 1333504225 ; 
$diffDay = floor($diff/(3600*24));
echo "\nDays from now : ".$diffDay;
```

Demo link : https://eval.in/716084